# How to concat multiple csv files into 1 file

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I am trying to concat multiple csv files into 1 file using python3. How can i do this. All the csv files in the same folder. When i used glob it gives me an error.

```
import glob
import csv

newfile = glob.glob('C:\Users\perera\Desktop\Machine Learning\RYU\data\dataset_1\*.csv')
```

and the error is

(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

what is the problem here

Comment: on linux: `$ cat *.csv > combined.csv`. there must be something similar on windows...

Comment: Add raw string --> `r'C:\Users\perera\Desktop\Machine Learning\RYU\data\dataset_1\*.csv'`

Comment: ...or use / as a directory separator (though a raw string is probably better)

Answer (score 3):

`\U` within a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) is interpreted as an escape sequence. Use a raw literal to avoid parsing of escape sequences.

```
newfile = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\perera\Desktop\Machine Learning\RYU\data\dataset_1\*.csv')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd;
import os;

frame = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f'dir/{f}') for f in os.listdir('dir') 
if f.endswith('.csv')])
```